# How to manipulate DOM after ng-show in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. I'm using angularjs version 1.2.13.
I've come upon a scenario where after ng-show displays my DIV, I need to manipulate the DOM in order to realign some DIV columns. I cannot realign my DIVs if they are hidden.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-show="IsThisShown">

    <div class="column">1</div>
    <div class="column">2</div>
    <div class="column">3</div>

</div>
```

I think the way to go would be to create a "realign" directive such as:

```
<div class="column" realign>1</div>
<div class="column" realign>2</div>
<div class="column" realign>3</div>
```

But I'm not sure how I would make the directive trigger only when the parent DIV is shown (through the ng-show directive).

Any ideas ?

Thanks appreciated!

Here's a little more code:

```
module.controller("MyController", function($scope, FormState){

    $scope.$watch(function(){ return FormState.showGrid; }, function(newVal, oldVal){

        //At this point in time, right here, the DOM has not been updated...

        $scope.IsThisShown = newVal; 

        //At this point in time, right here the DOM has still not been updated...


        //the DOM gets updated when the function exists
    });

});
```

Comment: How are you trying to realign the columns?

Comment: You could place your realigning logic in whatever sets your `IsThisShown` to TRUE

Comment: The truth is I'm not trying to realign the divs. It's just an example to focus the problem on how to manipulate de DOM after an ng-show happened. I'm actually using a jquery plugin called perfectScrollbar. This plugin has a method called "update" that I need to call but I haven't been able to make it work successfully because the method doesn't work if the DIV is hidden. After the DIV is shown through the usage of ng-show, I need to call $("#someDiv").perfectScrollbar("update")

Comment: @Slytherin I tried that but at the point in time the DIV is still not displayed. It only gets displayed when it comes out of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options.

One option you can explore is using an isolate scope with your `realign` directive.

See this example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lO2U4GZcEm4K1qGLpsFV

You don't have to use the isolate scope as Angular scope is prototypical by nature (though with a slight gotcha with regards to primitives), but I figured I'd throw this into the example so you can see isolate scope in action.  In this example I'm using an isolate scope with an execute expression.

Just a random example that builds on your description by randomly repositioning some div's after the parent is shown.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: The plunker proves the solution really works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways, but the way that immediately comes to mind is:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-show="IsThisShown">
    <div class="column" realign="IsThisShown">1</div>
    <div class="column" realign="IsThisShown">2</div>
    <div class="column" realign="IsThisShown">3</div>
</div>
```

And have your new directive observe its argument and do the realignment when it goes true.

Comment: I see where you're getting at. This should work! I'll try it later to confirm.

Comment: You were the first one to provide the general idea of the solution but brianmarco's provided more detail and a plunker which helped me quickly validate. Thanks for the effort though, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good (and standard), but tie the realign directive to being shown/hidden by that variable. If, for example, there are two nested ng-show's, this would break down. In my opinion, a better solution is to create an on-show directive, with the following scope:

```
scope: { 'onShow' : '&' }
```

And within the link function, set up a $scope.$watch as follows:

```
$scope.$watch(
  function() { return $element.hasClass('ng-hide'); }, 
  function(newVal, oldVal) { /* execute onShow here if newVal === false */ }
);
```

You could also (and I don't recommend this) change ng-show to ng-if. ng-if removes and adds the elements from the DOM, instead of just hiding them. In that case, the link function fires every time the element reappears.